# Problems with Django admin

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm trying to configure the admin in django 1.9 and have some trouble doing it.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kim Runar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Kim Runar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 323, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user
```

I have also tried to use this command but i get basically the same error-message. I'm using PyCharm 5.0.4

```
>>> python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Comment: Have you ran `migrate`?.

Comment: Try makemigrations and migrate

Comment: at very first you need to run `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` to get your databases set up first.

Comment: So easy! Thank you guys. Will accept as soon as i can